React 19's useOptimistic hook causes re-render of an entire array
I am still learning and trying out the new features from React 19's RC.
Recently I've started to work on a simple real-time chat-app.
This is how function that is ran using useActionState and uses useOptimistic looks like (inside of Textarea component):
const handleSubmit = (_prevState: string, queryData: FormData) => {
    const message = queryData.get("message") as string;
    if (user && message) {
      startTransition(async () => {
        addOptimisticMessage({
          $id: "optimistic_message",
          ...
        });
        await submitAction(message, attachments);
      });
    }
  };

This is where I actually initialize the useOptimistic inside of a Room component:
const [optimisticMessages, addOptimisticMessage] = useOptimistic(
    messages,
    (currentState: MessageObject[], newMessage: MessageObject) => [
      newMessage,
      ...currentState,
    ],
  );

And then this is how I map the array:
{optimisticMessages.map((message: MessageObject, index: number) => (
  <Message key={message.$id} message={message} />
))}

Now to describe the problem:

Optimistic message is added to the messages array without any problem, it doesn't cause re-render of the other components.
<- This works just fine and as expected.

An actual message is added and the optimistic message is removed -> this is where the problem occurs as the optimistic message gets replaced by the actual one from database and a re-render of all the messages occurs.


Now, I am not updating the state of messages inside of the submitAction() function but I have a listener set up inside of the Room component that whenever a new message is added it updates the state.
useEffect(() => {
    if (room && room.$id) {
      const unsubscribeMessages = client.subscribe(
        `databases.${database}.collections.messages.documents`,
        (response) => {
          const payload = response.payload as MessageObject;
          const messageRoomId = payload.room.$id;
          console.log(payload);
          if (messageRoomId === room.$id)
            setMessages((prevMessages) => [payload, ...prevMessages]);
        },
      );

      return () => {
        unsubscribeMessages();
      };
    }
  }, [room?.$id]);

^ When I comment out the addOptimistic() function in the Textarea component, it works just fine, so the cause of this re-render isn't inside of this hook.

I think these dependencies[room?.$id] may vary and cause re-render. May you try with [room]?

Okay, I tried it with the [room] but it's still the same, with or without the strict mode.
I suppose that I will need to create a codepen or something to demonstrate this.

I think re-renders may be caused by <ScrictMode />. In development, this component re-render items to catch bugs in your code. You may find some code like this:
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

To avoid re-renders try to remove <StrictMode />:
import { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);

And all works fine. But be notified that in production re-renders will disappear.

Hello, it didn't help.
The same issue persists in the production build.

While <StrictMode /> does render the dom an extra time, useOptimistic is not one of the hooks that strict mode checks an extra time. That is just Effects and Refs.

To prevent re-rendering of all messages when the optimistic message is replaced by the actual message, you can utilize React's useMemo to memoize the optimisticMessages array. This ensures that the messages only re-render when there is a change in the message array itself, rather than on each state update.
Here's the modified Room component with the memoized messages:
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';

const Room = ({ room, messages, client, database }) => {
  const [optimisticMessages, addOptimisticMessage] = useOptimistic(
    messages,
    (currentState: MessageObject[], newMessage: MessageObject) => [
      newMessage,
      ...currentState,
    ],
  );

  const memoizedMessages = useMemo(() => optimisticMessages, [optimisticMessages]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (room && room.$id) {
      const unsubscribeMessages = client.subscribe(
        `databases.${database}.collections.messages.documents`,
        (response) => {
          const payload = response.payload as MessageObject;
          const messageRoomId = payload.room.$id;
          if (messageRoomId === room.$id)
            setMessages((prevMessages) => [payload, ...prevMessages]);
        },
      );

      return () => {
        unsubscribeMessages();
      };
    }
  }, [room?.$id]);

  return (
    <div>
      {memoizedMessages.map((message: MessageObject, index: number) => (
        <Message key={message.$id} message={message} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Room;

In the Textarea component, keep your handleSubmit function as is:
const handleSubmit = (_prevState: string, queryData: FormData) => {
  const message = queryData.get("message") as string;
  if (user && message) {
    startTransition(async () => {
      addOptimisticMessage({
        $id: "optimistic_message",
        // additional message properties
      });
      await submitAction(message, attachments);
    });
  }
};

This way, memoizedMessages ensures that the Message components only re-render when there is an actual change in the optimisticMessages array, preventing unnecessary re-renders when the optimistic message is replaced by the actual message.

I've tested your code and for some reason it still has the same results.
To elaborate further, basically always when a new message is added I see something like a "jump" animation of sorts that the messages are being re-rendered.

If I'm understanding your issue correctly, I believe there is a misconception here. useOptimistic doesn't nor is it suppose to change the permanent state.
Per the docs:

optimisticState: The resulting optimistic state. It is equal to state unless an action is pending, in which case it is equal to the value returned by updateFn.

What this means is that the value returned by the updateFn function, or in your case
(currentState: MessageObject[], newMessage: MessageObject) => [
  newMessage,
  ...currentState,
],

is only a temporary value that is shown while an action is pending. Let's look at your problem:

An actual message is added and the optimistic message is removed -> this is where the problem occurs as the optimistic message gets replaced by the actual one from database and a re-render of all the messages occurs.

So when "an actual message is added and the optimistic message is removed" that is because your action was no longer in the pending state, your optimistic value was no more, and the value then became the updated state after your action had finished. This is the expected behavior.
Here is a useOptimistic example for reference:
import { useOptimistic } from 'react';
function AppContainer() {
const [optimisticState, addOptimistic] = useOptimistic(state,
// updateFn
(currentState, optimisticValue) => {
  // merge and return new state
  // with optimistic value
});}

That being said, if your issue is that everything is being re-rendered, that would be because your state object is being reinstantiated instead of mutated. I would clean up your logic, specifically, inside the startTransition hook. For starters, you're passing an async function inside of it which seems to be another misconception on how it works. Per the startTransition docs:

The function you pass to startTransition must be synchronous...
startTransition hook

